# Is there a way to make this custom function faster using pandas and/or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns of interest. Each column has hour:minute values seperated by "/" sign. They correspond to departure and arrival times. What I want to do is to calculate the waiting times between each arrival and next departure and output if any of the waiting times are > 8 hours. I have written a function which does it, but it is very slow. My data has > 2 million entrie. Here is the sample dataframe named `sample`:

```py
    segmentDepartureTimes   segmentArrivalTimes
0   20:10/07:45/10:05/17:05 22:00/09:00/11:10/19:05
1   07:20/11:25/13:10   08:55/12:15/14:40
2   20:50/11:25/13:10   22:25/12:15/14:40
3   16:50/21:15/19:00   18:10/22:05/20:40
4   15:50/21:15/19:00   17:10/22:05/20:40
```

So, in the first row, it will be time difference between 22:00 and 07:45, 09:00 and 10:05, 11:10 and 17:05. Here is the function I have written:

```py
def long_layover(departureSegments, arrivalSegments):
    a = departureSegments.split("/")
    b = arrivalSegments.split("/")
    # we need to remove the first element from departures and last from arrivals
    aa = pd.Series(a[1:])
    bb = pd.Series(b[:-1])
    
    def time_difference_pandas(time1, time2):
        time1_dt = pd.to_datetime(time1, format="%H:%M").dt.time
        time2_dt = pd.to_datetime(time2, format="%H:%M").dt.time
        time1_str = [time.strftime("%H:%M") for time in time1_dt]
        time2_str = [time.strftime("%H:%M") for time in time2_dt]
        difference = abs((pd.to_datetime(time2_str, infer_datetime_format=True) - 
                          pd.to_datetime(time1_str, infer_datetime_format=True)).total_seconds() / 3600)
        return difference
    
    hours = time_difference_pandas(bb, aa)
    
    return (hours>8).any()
```

The output on the sample would be:

```py
sample[["segmentDepartureTimes", "segmentArrivalTimes"]].apply(lambda x: long_layover(x[0], x[1]), axis = 1)

0       True
1      False
2       True
3      False
4      False
```

Is there a way to make this function more efficient? Maybe using some vectorization? Thank you in advance

Comment: Solution below not fast enough? no reaction?

Answer (score 0):

For a dataframe with 1000 entries it took with your version 1.71 seconds

```
%timeit df[["segmentDepartureTimes", "segmentArrivalTimes"]].apply(lambda x: long_layover(x[0], x[1]), axis = 1)

1.71 s ± 7.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I wrote following code based on the data you gave, which gives me a run tim of 3.83 milli seconds, factor 446!

```
def faster(df):

    df.segmentDepartureTimes = df.segmentDepartureTimes.str[6:]
    df.segmentArrivalTimes = df.segmentArrivalTimes.str[:-6]
    
    deps = df.segmentDepartureTimes.str.split("/", expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
    arvs = df.segmentArrivalTimes.str.split("/", expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
    
    return ((arvs - deps) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).gt(8).any(axis=1)
```

stats:

```
%timeit faster(df)

3.83 ms ± 39.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The reason why it is faster is, that I do not apply any calculation row by row, but using pandas advantages to do calculations at one go.

Edit:
2 million entries took 3.22 seconds by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = (
    sample["segmentDepartureTimes"]
    .str.split("/", n=1, expand=True)[1]
    .str.split("/", expand=True)
    .apply(pd.to_datetime)
)
b = (
    sample["segmentArrivalTimes"]
    .str.rsplit("/", n=1, expand=True)[0]
    .str.split("/", expand=True)
    .apply(pd.to_datetime)
)
((b - a).abs() / pd.Timedelta(1, unit="h") > 8).any(axis=1)
```